# Excel Function For

Tags: excel, function, date, excel-2010

I'm trying to figure out the best way to pull data in order to satisfy a condition.

Basically with the data that I have, I have to find the Percentage of Requests where the column DueDate is within 5-10 ways of the column ReceivedDate.

I understand percentage is to find out (how many record satisfy this/all records) * 100 but I'm very new to Excel and not sure how to make a good formula to gather this data. Can anyone help me please?

```
Sample Data
Received Date  DueDate    DaysBetween
7/1/2016       7/11/2016    10
7/1/2016       7/23/2016    22
7/1/2016       7/4/2016      3
7/1/2016       6/25/2016     6
7/1/2016       7/8/2016      7
```

And lets say Received Date is in cell A1, Due Date in cell B1 and DaysBetween in cell C1..and the corresponding records are numbered appropriately underneath.

I would want to make a formula for a cell which basically would help me to return the number 3 based on the records, because only #1, #4 and #5 records satisfy the condition of DueDate being within 5-10 days of ReceivedDate. Obviously this is only 5 records, but I have a column of thousands more.

Comment: Show some mocked up test data and expected outcome. It will help us understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it all in one formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ABS(B2:B6-A2:A6)<=10)*(ABS(B2:B6-A2:A6)>=5))/COUNT(A2:A6)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Scott! Appreciate you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would handle this:

1) Create a new column titled "Within 5-10 Days?" In that column, each cell will have the following formula: `=IF(AND(ReceivedDate > DueDate - 10, ReceivedDate < DueDate - 5), "YES", "NO"`

2) At the bottom of that column, have a count: `=COUNTIF(Column_Reference, "YES")`

3) Then, you can divide that count by the total number of requests.